# Applying a function to each element of a group in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to find the first non-NA element of column `w` in each group and then construct a new variable which starts from the index of that non-NA element and follows this law of motion:
`k_{it+1}=k_{it}+s_{it+1}-s{it}`.

`i` denotes the group and `t` is time. `k_{i1}` comes from the first non-NA element of column `w`.

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```
 DF <- data.frame("time"=factor(c(1999,2000,2001,2002,1999,2000,2001,2002)),
             "i"=factor(c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b")),
             "w"=c(NA,1,2,4,4,NA,3,4), "s"= c(10,20,10,22,45,30,20,40))
```

And I want to add a new column to it:

`DF$k <- c(NA, 1, -9, 3, 4, -11, -21, -1)`

Comment: Can you explain the calculation for 1-2 value ? How do you get 1, 6  ?

Comment: 1 is the first non-NA row in column w, 6 is 1+25-20. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a function to calculate values using the formula :

```
library(dplyr)

apply_fun <- function(x,y){
  inds <- which.max(!is.na(x))
  vals <-rep(NA, length(x))
  c(rep(NA, inds - 1), Reduce(`+`, y[(inds+1):length(y)] - y[inds:(length(y) - 1)], 
                       accumulate = TRUE, init = x[inds]))
}
```

and then apply it by group

```
DF %>%
  group_by(i) %>%
  mutate(k = apply_fun(w, s))

# time  i         w     s     k
#  <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1999  a        NA    10    NA
#2 2000  a         1    20     1
#3 2001  a         2    10    -9
#4 2002  a         4    22     3
#5 1999  b         4    45     4
#6 2000  b        NA    30   -11
#7 2001  b         3    20   -21
#8 2002  b         4    40    -1
```

Comment: I think there is an issue: we should only use the first non-NA element of `w`, and then `k` evolves from its own previous values.

Comment: @Reabo Sorry, not clear to me. Can you include an example in your post which shows what you mean ?

Comment: I've changed the example in my question

Comment: @Reabo Can you explain how you get 3 or -21 in you calculation. If I use your code I get all `NA`s'.

Comment: for group b: 4(k1)=4 (first non-NA of column `w`),  -11(k2)=4(k1)+30(s2)-45(s1), and so on. The code works for me.

Comment: @Reabo I see..thanks I have updated the answer with `Reduce`, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works, however, I had to use `for` which I don't think would be fast enough for a big dataset:

```
apply_fun <- function(x,y){

   inds <- which.max(!is.na(x))
   vals <-rep(NA, length(x))
   vals[inds]<-x[inds]
      for (i in (inds+1):length(x)){
        vals[i] <- vals[i-1]+y[i]-y[i-1]

         }
vals
}


DF %>%
  group_by(i) %>%
  mutate(k = apply_fun(w, s))
```